# Interop Excel Automation - Open workbook with a service account

Tags: excel, interop

I am facing a situation here and would like some feedback or advice.
I have been given an application that run as a service, with a specific service account (not admin on the server), and try to open an Excel workbook.

The problem is not with the initial application, as I can reproduce it with the generic C# code below (embedded in a service structure):

```
try{
    this._exApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    this._exApp.Visible = false;

    Log.Logger.Info("Opening workbook...");
    Workbook workbook = this._exApp.Workbooks.Open(
                thisFileName,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing
                );
    Log.Logger.Info("Workbook opened!");

    //Do something with the result
    Log.Logger.Info("Closing workbook...");
    workbook.Close(false, thisFileName, null);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

    this._exApp.Quit();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    Log.Logger.Error(ex.Message);
}
```

(nothing special about *this._exApp* and *thisFileName*, which are just respectively casted to a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application, and as a string with the path of the file to open. Log.Logger is a a logger class using log4net to allow me seeing when the problem occurs)

The service is running as a service account, which is a user on the server, not an admin. It has access to the target file and to files on the server (as Read access). The server is a Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP2 (could not try yet on a 2008 R2 server).

The problem I am facing is that it just hangs when trying to open the workbook, so in terms of tracing the last line I have is "Opening workbook...", never reaching the "Workbook opened" line. No exception is raised.

So the code is very simple, it is just trying to open an excel workbook. I have done already some investigations, and here are my findings:

- I know that Microsoft does not support a server side Excel automation, but I have been given the service as it, and do not have a choice about the technology used.
- I have configured all the Component Services/DCOM/Microsoft Excel Application security settings so that the service account has all the permissions possible.
- The service does the job correctly if the service account is local admin on the machine. This is not really on option for production.
- The service does the job correctly if the file it tries to open is a local file. Unfortunately, the file we tries to access is on a remote file server, and it does not work in that situation.
- The code above run from a command line with the same user on a remote file works fine, but not any more when run as a service.
- I have read about the *C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop* bug, but the folder exists.
- Excel open correctly when lauched with the service account.

So basically, the situation is the Workbooks.Open method hangs when run as a service, under a service account that is not admin, and when accessing a remote file.

I would appreciate any input or idea on this topic.

Thanks.

Jonathan

EDIT: As per Matt's workaround below, we have implemented a local copy of the remote file, so I am accepting it as an answer, but I remain interested in any suggestion on how to make it work directly on the remote file.

Comment: Could it be the remote location has not been defined as a "Trusted Location" in the Excel Trust Center options on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have put this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet, so this is more just a possible workaround rather than a full blown answer...

> The service does the job correctly if the file it tries to open is a local file. Unfortunately, the file we tries to access is on a remote file server, and it does not work in that situation.

Can you first copy the file from the remote server to a local temp location?

```
        this._exApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
        this._exApp.Visible = false;

        string localFile = "local.xls";
        System.IO.File.Copy(thisFileName, localFile);

        Log.Logger.Info("Opening workbook...");
        Workbook workbook = this._exApp.Workbooks.Open(localFile, ...);
        Log.Logger.Info("Workbook opened!");
```

Comment: Hello Matt, this is indeed what we ended up doing in order to get the service running (copying locally, opening then deleting). This is not ideal, and would have liked to understand what is preventing it on on a remote file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry, wanted to up your answer, but I am too new as well (15 RP required...) ;)

Comment: Thanks. If this workaround is working for you then you can mark it as the accepted answer (check mark to the left) so others with the same/similar problem will easily know that this worked for you. When/if a real solution (or a better workaround) comes around then you can change the selected answer to that. If you find a solution or better workaround then you can post an answer to your own question and then mark it as the accepted solution (nothing wrong with that!). That way other people can easily find the current "best" solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Crazy or not, you need to create the following folder

C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop (32bit)
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop (64bit)

Something to do with Excel running through Scheduler by using the system account....

Comment: Dont know how but this black magic works.